# Evaluate elisp in Bookmarks File

Tags: bookmarks

Is there a reasonable way to evaluate elisp within a bookmarks file in Emacs?

For example, I bookmark all of my typical remote file paths and am in the middle of trying to get a dynamic IP address set up on a local machine. I have the following lines in my file '~/.emacs.d/bookmarks':

```
("example-remote-file"
 (filename . "/scp:tdstoff@10.111.X.XX:/file/path/"))
```

But without setting a dynamic host, a network reset can change the path to something like `"/scp:tdstoff@10.112.X.XX"`. A handy solution for the time being would be to evaluate something like
`(setq my-remote-ip "10.112.X.X")`
at initialization and then have the following in the bookmarks file:

```
("example-remote-file"
 (filename . (concat "/scp:tdstoff@" my-remote-ip ":/file/path/"))).
```

Is something like this reasonably possible? Currently I get a completion related error:
`Error in post-command-hook (vertico--exhibit): (wrong-type-argument stringp (concat my-remote-ip "/scp:tdstoff@10.112.X.XX:/file/path/"))`

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.  A bookmarks file is *read* as Elisp code (a list), but it's not *evaluated*.

What you can do is use a different bookmark type, e.g., one that you define, which has a handler that does what you want.